# PostgreSQL: Query elements in a JSON array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a database table like the following:

```
---------------------------------------
| id | json_array (jsonb)             |
---------------------------------------
|  1 | [{"a": 1}, {"a": 5}, {"a": 1}] |
|  2 | [{"a": 2}]                     |
|  3 | [{"a": 1}]                     |
---------------------------------------
```

I want to use PostgreSQL's JSON query abilities to select certain sub dictionaries in the `json_array` array, e.g. dictionaries where `"a": 1`.

The output should be

```
------------------
| id | json_dict |
------------------
|  1 | {"a": 1}  |
|  1 | {"a": 1}  |
|  3 | {"a": 1}  |
------------------
```

The following query works for the first element in each array, but I want to check for all of them:

```sql
SELECT id, json_array -> 0
FROM my_table
WHERE json_array -> 0 -> "a" = 1;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=96b4218476e77e470f7059641c56515a)

You can expand your array elements into one element each row with `jsonb_array_elements()`. This can be filtered:

```
SELECT
    id,
    elems.value
FROM
    mytable,
    jsonb_array_elements(data) elems
WHERE
    elems.value = '{"a":1}'
```

Answer (score 9):

Assuming this is a JSONB column, you can use the `@>` operator with a json object:

```
select *
from my_table
where json_array @> '[{"a": 1}]';
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/SACUDU51598

If you want all objects as rows, you need to unnest the array:

```
select t.id, e.obj
from data t
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(json_array) as e(obj)
where e.obj = '{"a": 1}'
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/DLG27322